# How to test properties atomically in nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, fluent-assertions

Given an object with several properties, say System.Drawing.Rectangle, I wanted to assert the values of ALL the properties (not stopping when ONE property didn't match) and report ALL the properties.

I tried this code, hoping it would do what I wanted...

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle croppingRectangle = SomeMethodReturnsRectangle(testP1,testP2);
Assert.That(()=>{ croppingRectangle.X==testX && croppingRectangle.Y==testY },"expected X={0}, Y={1} but was X={2},Y={3}", testX,testY,croppingRectangle.X,croppingRectangle.Y);
```

Whats the correct way in NUnit to do this?

(I realize this works:)

```
if(croppingRectangle.X==testX && croppingRectangle.Y==testY) {
    Assert.Pass();
else
    Assert.Fail("expected X={0}, Y={1} but was X={2},Y={3}", testX,testY,croppingRectangle.X,croppingRectangle.Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you *don't* want to make the type itself check for equality and override `ToString`? Because that would do it nice.

One option would be to use anonymous types to accomplish the same goal:

```
Assert.AreEqual(new { X = testX, Y = testY },
                new { croppingRectangle.X, croppingRectangle.Y });
```

Due to the way anonymous types work (with `Equals` and `ToString` being autogenerated) this should give you a nice error message *and* check all the properties at the same time. It does rely on the per-property equality check being the default check for each property type though.

Comment: Since I'm (technically) unable to change the core library, then I have to check myself.  Interesting approach on the new anonymous types, I will try that and report back.

Comment: REPORTING BACK: So this works nice... the anonymous types generate the Equals like you said... but seems a bit cumbersome still.

Comment: @enorl76: It looks less cumbersome to me than the code you hoped would work. If you need to do this on a regular basis for some particular type, you could create a `ToAnonymousType` extension method on that type.

Answer (score 0):

If your rectangle is some sort of a value object, you could rely on the `.Equals` method to compare the whole object at a time.

Or, you could just append to a list the errors.

```
var errors = new List<String>()

if(croppingRectangle.Prop == ExpectedValue) {
    //test
}
else {errors.add("ErrorMessage");}

.... and so on

Assert.IsEqual(errors.Count, 0);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid long if/else statements

Answer (score 0):

Or you use Fluent Assertions to verify your object against an anonymous object that contains the expected properties and values. See http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2012/09/asserting-object-graph-equivalence.html